# href links behind images don't work in ie

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer, href

I want to put some links to other pages behind images, some of the images links work in internet explorer (the images in the header), some of them don't (images in my page)

The images are clickable but the page just doesn't load, I can see it's linked correct because when I hover over the image it shows me the pad.

this is my code:

This is the code of the non-working images, i put the style and important tags there because that made it work on the other link images.

```
<div class="buttonlinks">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <a href="modeling.html" style="text-decoration:none !important;"><img border="0" src="images/Knop1Layer.PNG" class="button"></a>
      <div class="tekstblok">
      <ul class="buttontekst">
        <li>HEALTH ECONOMIC MODELS</li>
        <li>BUDGET IMPACT</li>
        <li>Art. 81 TOOLS</li>
        <li>VALUE  TOOLS</li>
        <li>…</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <a href="data analyse.html" style="text-decoration:none !important;"><img border="0" src="images/Knop2Layer.PNG" class="button"></a>
        <div class="tekstblok">
      <ul class="buttontekst">
        <li>EPIDEMOLOGY</li>
        <li>SCENARIO ANALYSIS</li>
        <li>PRICE OPTIMISATION</li>
        <li>FORCASTING</li>
        <li>…</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.buttonlinks {
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #D9D9D9;  
    min-height: 300px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.thumbnail {
    position: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 35px;
    padding-left: 8%;
    padding-right: 11.1%;
}
.button {
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #000;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.button:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: #FEFEFE;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.buttontekst{
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```

This is the code of the working buttons:

```
<a href="MA activities.html" style="text-decoration:none !important;"><img src="images/Knop3Front.PNG" class="navbuttons"></a>
        <img src="images/Knop2Front.PNG" id="current" class="navbuttons">
        <a href="modeling.html" style="text-decoration:none !important;"><img src="images/Knop1Front.PNG" class="navbuttons"></a>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.navbuttons{
    max-height: 20%;
    max-width: 20%;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    float: right;
}

#current{
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file extension is `.png` instead of `.PNG` as it is very likely your server is running under a Linux distro, whose file system is [usually case-sensitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Features).

Also, your file structure should be something similar to:

- images/

  - Knop1Layer.png
  - Knop2Layer.png
- index.html

If your HTML file isn't stored in the root directory, you might need to use the absolute path, so `images/Knop1Layer.png` should be `/images/Knop1Layer.png` instead.

Comment: when i add the / to my path the picture disappears. The png in upper or lower case doesn't change anything.

Comment: Are your images stored in your server root (/images) or are they stored in a different subdirectory?

Comment: it's stored within an extra folder, the server root

Comment: Then you can set it to `/folderName/images/imageName.png` instead. You can learn more about how to format your URLs by reading up docs on relative and absolute URLs and when you should use one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

the problem in the second image is the space in the url

Comment: that's just the file name, shouldn't give any problems i suppose? the first image doesn't work without a space either

Comment: I just tried your code in my own project. It works fine. The only thing that could be wrong is your internet explorer settings. Microsoft is infamous for this.

Comment: sure no problem. Please mark right if that is the issue. I could use the points

Comment: edit: the problem only situates in my home page, text link doesn't work either...

Comment: use a ~ before the /images